# Get last inserts of the disctinct property type list in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of Account. Each Account document has 3 properties _id, type, age; and there are 3 distinct types Male,Female & Other. Any single document will bear only one of the types.

```
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx1),
type:"Male",
age:20

}
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx2),
type:"Female",
age:20

}
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx3),
type:"Male",
age:21

}
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx4),
type:"Other",
age:30

}
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx5),
type:"Female",
age:31

}
```

My problem is I want to extract very last inserted document of each three type:
The result will be 3 documents

```
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx3), <--- last insert of the Male type
type:"Male",
age:21

}
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx4), <--- last insert of the Other type
type:"Other",
age:30

}
{
_id:ObjectId(xxxxx5), <--- last insert of the Female type
type:"Female",
age:31

}
```

How can I design query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MongoDB's [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) :

```
db.Account.aggregate([
      {$group : {_id : '$type', lastDoc : {$last : '$$ROOT'}}},
      {$replaceRoot : {newRoot : '$lastDoc'}}])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JyKWDVkB1uR)

**Explanation :**

1. In aggregate `$group` stage will group all the matching docs based on condition `_id : '$type'`, So all the docs with same `type` will be grouped together & using `$last` we'll get the last document in the grouping process.
2. Using `replaceRoot` we'll make `lastDoc` object as new root of the document.

Comment: Just awesome! !